# Lexicographically earliest sequence with shift-sum property

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

*I use $\mathbb{N}$ to denote the set of non-negative integers.*

Let $a: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $a(n+a(n+1)) = a(n) + a(n+1)$. Two trivial examples are $a(n) = 0$ and $a(n) = n$. But if we require $a(n+1) > 0$, we eliminate the former. Now let $a_0$ be the lexicographically earliest sequence of this kind, do we necessarily have

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_0(n+1) = \min \{k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, a_0(n+k) = a_0(n) + k\}$$

and assuming this to be true, can we show $a_0(n) \le n$?

I wrote a program using these assumptions to produce the terms

$$0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 10, 2, 12, 9, 3, 10, 12, 2, 14, 17,$$
$$3, 21, 20, 14, 13, 2, 15, 22, 2, 24, 3, 16, 27, 2, 29, 31$$

which may or may not be the initial terms of $a_0$. All I know for sure is that, for any sequence $a$ with the shift-sum property, there can be no zeros or ones after $n=1$ and no zeros or ones at all if $a(0) \neq 0$, so any help answering these questions will be greatly appreciated.

I have plotted the terms above in GeoGebra [here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/qdhsxp3b). I don't have any more terms because the program I used to compute them seems to enter an infinite loop after $n = 35$. The program in question can be found [here](https://github.com/shadow8475/Compute-Sequence/blob/main/compute.py).

---

**Edit 1**: I am calling the proposition
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : a(n+a(n+1)) = a(n) + a(n+1) \text{ and } a(n+1) > 0$$
the shift-sum property. A sequence is said to exhibit the **least shift-sum property** if $a(n+1)$ is always the least positive integer $k$ such that $a(n+k) = a(n) + k$.

I now realise I have made some undue assumptions about the existence of a lexicographic minimum for some class of sequences, and the existence of sequences with the *least shift-sum* property described above. I also assumed that $a_0(0) = 0$, however this may not be true even if $a_0$ does in fact exist. Motivated by the discussion in the comments below, I ask the following question to help dispel the confusion.

**Do there exist sequences of natural numbers with the *least shift-sum* property?**

---

**Edit 2**: I have just realised that the output of my program proves that at least one of my initial assumptions is incorrect. In the output we get $a(2) = 2$, but $k = 1$ is actually the least such that $a(n+k) = a(n)+k$, hence the output must rely on a false assumption. Moreover, my program enters an infinite loop because $a(23) = 14$ requires $a(35) = 34$ but $a(24) = 13$ requires $a(35) = 27$.

> If a sequence has the least shift-sum property, then two adjacent terms $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ can only be consecutive integers if $a(n) = 0$ and $a(n+1) = 1$. This follows from $a(n+1)$ being $a(n) + 1$. Therefore, if both assumptions are true then $a_0$ cannot start $0,1,2$. But there are no other possibilities if $a_0(n) \le n$.

**I conjecture that, if $a_0$ does indeed exist, then $a_0(n) \le n$ and that there are no sequences of natural numbers with the *least shift-sum* property.**

Comment: @CalvinLin That is what I originally thought, but how do we know there actually exists a sequence satisfying the recurrence relation with that choice for $a(n+1)?$

Comment: @CalvinLin replying to your previous comment: I am not sure I follow, since for $a(n) = n$, $a(n+1)$ is only the least $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a(n+k)=a(n)+k$ when $n=0$

Comment: @CalvinLin I require $a(n+1) > 0$ and if $a(n+1) = 1$ then $a(n+1) = a(n) + a(n+1)$ implies $a(n) = 0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123946/discussion-between-thomas-king-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: @CalvinLin It's looking like $a_0$ is indeed just $a_0(n) = n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin How do you show the set of sequences (with the shift-sum property) is well-ordered, since $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \setminus \{(0,0,...)\}$ is not well-ordered?

Comment: I deleted my individual comments since a lot of them were wrong. To summarize, A) The condition need not hold on $a_0$, since we might need to set a slightly larger value in order to extend the sequence down the road (and this seems to be the case) B) We can show that the infimum still satisfies the functional equation (When the first k+1 terms are equal, then the equation holds for k), hence a minimum does exist.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see now that you are referring to the least shift-sum property as "the condition", so part A makes sense. I will have to think a bit more about part B.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a solution. Too long to be a comment.)

This is how I'm thinking of showing that the infimum is a SSP.

- Consider all sequences with SSP.
- Consider the first element, pick the smallest (which turns out to be 0).

  - Focus on sequences with this first element, pick the smallest second element.
- Focus on sequences with these first 2 elements,

  - we do have $a( 0 + a(1) ) = a(0) + a(1)$ by definition, which will uniquely define a subsequent term.
  - Pick the smallest third element.
- Focus on sequences with these first 3 elements,

  - we do have $ a(1 + a(2) ) = a(1) + a(2) $ by definition, which will uniquely define a subsequent term.
  - Pick the smallest fourth element.
- We continue this process iteratively

  - We can always continue this, since there exists at least 1 SSP with those initial $k$ elements, so we can pick the smallest $k+1$ element.
  - At each step, we have $ a( k + a(k+1) ) = a(k) + a(k+1)$.

Comment: I think this is logically equivalent to what my program implements, and that ran into a problem because two, seemingly free, choices forced a contradiction later down the line.

Comment: Well actually, neither $a(23)$ nor $a(24)$ are free (in the program output), but they are forced by free choices near the start.

Comment: I see where this defers from my program, I assumed $a_0(n) \le n$ which this doesn't. Because each choice is now unbounded, this cannot be implemented with backtracking, so computing the sequence will be difficult.

Comment: Also, in my program I assumed picking the smallest is valid (and it turned out it wasn't) but this doesn't have that problem because you pick the smallest which belongs to a sequence with SSP (so the choices which lead to a contradiction are discounted). Therefore, to compute the sequence $a_0$ you need to know all sequence with SSP.

Comment: Maybe all SSP sequences are of the form $a(n) = n + m$? This would imply $a_0(n) = n$.